# Is there a way to get rid of the [1] from a string in R?

Tags: php, r, string

Basically, I'm creating strings of Data from R that will be piped into PHP via a PHP wrapper and command line. The string outputs perfectly and everything, except the pesky "[1]" remains in the output. Is there a way I could get rid of this and just have the quote?

Comment: Can you show us how you're doing it? If it's through `print()`, it will have the `[1]`. Using `cat()` will get rid of this.

Comment: Oh, I'm converting a column of strings into one big string, and just trying to return it. cat() worked nicely! Thank you!